# Why grep can't filter the right line in shell script?

Tags: shell, grep

The code is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$(cat b.txt | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]" | tr -c "[:alnum:]" '\n' | grep -v "^$")

cat a.txt | while read line; do
    file=$(echo "$file" | grep -ov "$line")
done
echo "$file" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

The above **a.txt** is a file with a paragraph and **b.txt** is file with some words each line, and i just want to delete these words in **b.txt** from **a.txt**, while the answer is wrong.

for example:

**b.txt**

```
Hello, i want to go to school
```

**a.txt**

```
hello
i
```

**Expected result:**

```
  1 go
  1 school
  1 want
  2 to
```

**Actual result:**

```
  1 go
  1 hello
  1 i
  1 school
  1 want
  2 to
```

while my answer also include the word included in b.txt.

Comment: Can you please add sample content of a.txt, b.txt and your expected results

Comment: Sorry, and an example is added.

Comment: you wrote *the answer is wrong* . Can you post the proper expected result?

Comment: Sorry, i got it wrong.And i now post the generated answer by shell and my expected answer.

Comment: Are the words in the files unique? Then you could concat the files and use the ``uniq`` options to output only unique / only duplicate words.

Comment: It's a bit different, i want the words in a.txt while doesn't include in b.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the classic subshell variable problem, caused by the useless use of cat.  Since you are piping cat to the while loop and pipelines run in a subshell, the assignments to the variable `file` affect the subshell only.  The original variable is not modified.  Easiest solution is to write `while read line; do ... done < a.txt`

A second solution is to echo the variable from the subshell:

```
cat a.txt | { while read line; do
    file=$(echo "$file" | grep -ov "$line")
done
echo "$file" | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, these solutions helps me.

Answer (score 1):

**AWK** approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN {
    FS="[,[:space:]]";
}
{
    if (NR==FNR) {
        for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){
            black[tolower($i)]=1;
        }
        next;
    }
    for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
        if ($i && black[tolower($i)]!=1) {
            target[tolower($i)]+=1;
        }
    }
}
END {
    for (i in target) {
        print target[i], i;
    }
}' a.txt b.txt
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1 want
1 go
2 to
1 school
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a correct answer, while i just want to know why my script doesn't work.

Comment: Glad it helps, just a piece of cake.